# About Terence Tao's blog-notes on complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

I'm planning to have a first-read in *complex analysis* before I study advanced texts like *Stein-Shakarchi* or *Remmert*. So I was looking for some basic notes or book geared towards **setting strong foundations** in the concepts.

**Terence Tao**'s complex analysis notes are posted in his blog (Note that the order of the notes are newest-first, i.e. the first post is at the bottom of the page and the last is on the top). Here's the link:
https://terrytao.wordpress.com/category/teaching/246a-complex-analysis/

**What are the pre-requisites of these sets of notes?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is asking personal advice, which is out of scope for this site.  Instead, you could ask for the prerequisites for those notes.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I've edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Tao's notes are more advanced then Stein-Shakarchi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've never completed the usual reading found in a first course on complex analysis, then I would recommend that you begin by studying either 1) *Schaum's Outline of Complex Variables*, 2) Churchill and Brown's *Complex Variables*, or 3) Saff and Snider's *Fundamentals of Complex Analysis*.  (A useful book that is slightly more advanced than these is Taylor's *Complex Variables*, published by the AMS.)

Then you should be able to have a go at Tao's notes or even at the textbooks you mentioned.